# Determine size of list in Map<Integer, List<String>> in JSTL <c:if>

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have the following map:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesById= new HashMap<>() ;
```

I want to iterate through the map in jsp. However, first I want to check if the list size is bigger than a certain number first.

So what I want to is this (putting test number for demonstration purposes):

```
if (namesById.get(1).size() > 3)
for (String s: namesById.get(1)){
        do something
   }
```

I need to do it in JSP. Since I am a beginner in JSTL I don't exactly know how to write it and it is hard to debug. I tried with this expression:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(namesById[1]) gt 3}"

</c:if>
```

So what I want to do is:

1. First get the list from the map by giving the specific key
2. Then check if the size of the list is bigger a certain number
3. And then iterate through the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because

```
Integer.valueOf(1).equals(Long.valueOf(1))
```

is always `false`.

In Expression language, `${1}` is interpreted as `Long` and this doesn't match the `Integer` key. Basically, you're effectively doing a `namesById.get(1L)` here.

Change your map to be `Map<Long, List<String>>` and it'll work.

Answer (score -1):

Using Jstl you can get the key and value from map.Using that value you can check the size.Check following example.

```
<%
    Map<Integer, List<String>> namesById = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    namesById.put(1, list);

    list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    namesById.put(2, list);
    pageContext.setAttribute("itemList", namesById);
%>


<c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="entry">
  <c:if test="${fn:length(entry.value) gt 3}">
    Value > 3
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```